# How can I display an exception when I use Monolog's ExceptionHandler?

Tags: php, monolog

in my usecase, I want to display (when developing) an exception thrown in my php-application.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

...

throw new Exception();
```

This works as it should. When I throw an exception, I will receive it in my http-response from apache (within the returned HTML).

Now, I want to use [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/) for logging. I integrate it, everything works fine, exception is logged to file by Monolog, for example.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

...

$exception_log = new Logger('exception');
\Monolog\ErrorHandler::register($exception_log, false, null, false);

...

throw new Exception();
```

But, the exception is not send in the html-part of the http-response any more. So it is not displayed in my browser when I do my http-request.

How do I use Monolog to log my exceptions, and still "display" them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add you own exception handler.

For example :

```
function echo_exception_handler($e) {
  echo sprintf('Uncaught Exception %s: "%s" at %s line %s', get_class($e), $e->getMessage(), $e->getFile(), $e->getLine());
}
set_exception_handler('echo_exception_handler');

$exception_log = new Logger('exception');
...
```

Comment: I had hoped for a "cleaner" way, but hey, it works, thank you!
Could you explain, where this behavior comes from?

Comment: Monolog install its own exception handler (that's why the errors are no longer displayed), but it also call another exception handler if it was previously set